# Combining features with multiple similar field values to one and adding unique values as new fields using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, combine

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a table with several objects that are identical with the exception of one field that has several unique values.

How can I merge these multiple features into one and have the unique values added to that feature as new individual fields?

from:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| a       | b       | c       |
| a       | b       | d       |
| a       | b       | e       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

to :

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a       | b       | c       | d       | e       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this field calculator expression on new field:

```
aDict={}
def COMBO(a,b,c):
 aKey=(a,b)
 if aKey in aDict:aDict[aKey]+=[c]
 else: aDict[aKey]=[c]
 return '|'.join(aDict[aKey])
#--------------
COMBO( !Field_1!, !Field_2!, !Field_3!)
```

[image]

To pick last record I used Dissolve tool on first two fields and statistics (last) on a new field:

[image]

Create additional fields in output and populate them using split function.